# display div when clicking a button that has the same parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to have a div that is displayed when I click a button.

Right now I am only able to display something that is within the button I will click, like so:

```js
var header = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
  if (current.length > 0) { 
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
.mainmenu {
display: block;
width: 100% !important;
background: red;
height: auto;
}

.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: auto;
  widht: 100%;
}

/* Style the active class, and buttons on mouse-over */
.active, .btn:hover {
  background-color: #666;
  color: #fff;
}
.submenu > p {
display: none;
background: green;
}

.active p {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV">
<div class="mainmenu">
  <button class="btn">1
  <div class="submenu">
  <p> TEST1</p>
  </div>
  </button>
  </div>
  <div class="mainmenu">
  <button class="btn">2  <div class="submenu">
  <p> TEST2</p>
  </div></button>
    </div>
  <div class="mainmenu">
  <button class="btn">3  <div class="submenu">
  <p> TEST3</p>
  </div></button>
    </div>
  <div class="mainmenu">
  <button class="btn">4  <div class="submenu">
  <p> TEST4</p>
  </div></button>
    </div>
  <div class="mainmenu">
  <button class="btn">5  <div class="submenu">
  <p> TEST5</p>
  </div></button>  </div>
</div>
```

If I move the div I want to display out of the button, I know that I have to adjust the javascript code to still display the div which is now not in the button anymore. unfortunately I don't know how.

So I am basically trying to display the div (which is working in the first jsfiddle) when clicking a button, but now I want to move the div out of the button. (which I tried in the second jsfiddle)
When I moved the div out of the button the code is not working. I am sure that there is a problem with my javascript but I don't know how to fix that.

```js
var header = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
  if (current.length > 0) { 
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
.mainmenu {
display: block;
width: 100% !important;
background: red;
height: auto;
}

.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: auto;
  widht: 100%;
}

/* Style the active class, and buttons on mouse-over */
.active, .btn:hover {
  background-color: #666;
  color: #fff;
}
.submenu > p {
display: none;
background: green;
}

.active p {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV">
<div class="mainmenu">
  <button class="btn">1  </button>
  <div class="submenu">
  <p> TEST1</p>
  </div>

  </div>
  <div class="mainmenu">
  <button class="btn">2</button>  <div class="submenu">  
  <p> TEST2</p>
  </div>
    </div>
  <div class="mainmenu">
  <button class="btn">3</button>  <div class="submenu">
  <p> TEST3</p>
  </div>
    </div>
  <div class="mainmenu">
  <button class="btn">4</button>  <div class="submenu">
  <p> TEST4</p>
  </div>
    </div>
  <div class="mainmenu">
  <button class="btn">5</button>  <div class="submenu">
  <p> TEST5</p>
  </div>  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to do this and even align the buttons to the right but the div to the left?

Comment: Please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work.

Comment: Paste your code here unable to open URL

Answer (score 1):

Selecting the **`<p>`** tag in the CSS is wrong, as you have now moved the div outside so you have to select that like,

```
.active + .submenu p {
    ....
}
```

> `+` means the element immediately after the specified element but not
>   inside the particular elements.

Here is your updated code,

```js
var header = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
  if (current.length > 0) { 
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
.mainmenu {
display: block;
width: 100% !important;
background: red;
height: auto;
}

.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: auto;
  widht: 100%;
}

/* Style the active class, and buttons on mouse-over */
.active, .btn:hover {
  background-color: #666;
  color: #fff;
}
.submenu > p {
display: none;
background: green;
}

.active + .submenu p {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV">
<div class="mainmenu">
  <button class="btn">1  </button>
  <div class="submenu">
  <p> TEST1</p>
  </div>

  </div>
  <div class="mainmenu">
  <button class="btn">2</button>  <div class="submenu">  
  <p> TEST2</p>
  </div>
    </div>
  <div class="mainmenu">
  <button class="btn">3</button>  <div class="submenu">
  <p> TEST3</p>
  </div>
    </div>
  <div class="mainmenu">
  <button class="btn">4</button>  <div class="submenu">
  <p> TEST4</p>
  </div>
    </div>
  <div class="mainmenu">
  <button class="btn">5</button>  <div class="submenu">
  <p> TEST5</p>
  </div>  </div>
</div>
```